# How to Parse Returned JSON Array from PHP

Tags: java, php, android, json

**Json**

```
{
    "title": "lorem",
    "image": "ipsum",
    "0": "dummytext",
    "1": "printingandtypesetting",
    "2": "industry",
    // etc...
}
```

I'm returning array from **PHP** file.

How to parse this array in my App and use every item in the array for e.g **Title**, or loop through them then start a new Activity displaying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Google's GSON library (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse your JSON data.

You'd simply have to create a POJO class that holds the variables that are returned from your php file, and the GSON library can handle the rest.

This is how you could convert it into an object, if your class was named "Employee" (just as an example)

```
Employee employee = (Employee)gson.fromJson(InputString, new TypeToken<Employee>(){}.getType());
```

with "gson" being an instance of GSON, and "InputString" being your JSON string.

Comment: This is kinda complicated for me cuz i'm new in Java, but Thanks anyway for the help :) i would prefer not using any library just pure.